# Does anyone uses OpenFiler in production?

Tags: iscsi

Does anyone use OpenFiler (http://openfiler.com/) as an iSCSI target in production (especially in a hosting environment)?

If yes then on what hardware configuration and what problems occured during usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on production yet but getting ready for it. My experience so far is that as far as going to use to expose iscsi luns it would be fine. And works fine so far for me. I am running it in test mode yet but planning to run on poweredge 2950 with 1 PowerVault MD1120 with 24 drives, this will allow me to go upto 144 drives in single box.

Comment: What configuration you are planning to have for Dell PowerEdge 2950?

Comment: Hey mamu, since this was a while back, I assume you implemented this?  How has it worked out for you?

Comment: I didn't implement the way i mentioned in my answer at the end. But i have a tower server with 5 disks running openfiler which i am using as backup server. I am 100% satisfied with openfile it has been running like champ for last one year without any issue. Updating it is just click of a button and i updated it several times without any issue.

But I had not gone ahead with using it in production not because of software but hardware i needed something 100% redundent which require me to go with full service san provider(EMC)